# How do you change the default "Response content type" for Swagger to "application/json"?

Tags: swagger, sap-commerce-cloud

SAP Commerce Cloud version: 1905.9

Currently, the default "Response content type" for Swagger has 2 values: "application/xml" and "application/json". The default selection is "application/xml". Is there a way to change the default selection to "application/json"?

Sample vanilla code is like this:

```
@ApiOperation(hidden = true, value = "Updates the total amount of a specific product", notes = "Updates the total amount of a specific product in the cart based on the entryNumber.")
@RequestMappingOverride(priorityProperty = "b2bocc.CartResource.updateCartEntry.priority")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}/entries/{entryNumber}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
@ApiBaseSiteIdUserIdAndCartIdParam
public CartModificationWsDTO updateCartEntry(@ApiParam(value = "Base site identifier.") @PathVariable final String baseSiteId,
        @ApiParam(value = "The id of the entry in the cart.") @PathVariable final int entryNumber,
        @ApiParam(value = "New quantity for this entry.") @RequestParam(required = true) final Long quantity,
        @ApiParam(value = "Response configuration. This is the list of fields that should be returned in the response body.", allowableValues = "BASIC, DEFAULT, FULL") @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = FieldSetLevelHelper.DEFAULT_LEVEL) final String fields)
{

    return updateCartEntry(baseSiteId, null, entryNumber, quantity, fields);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Helen Updated question with Hybris OOTB/vanilla code. Note that Hybris has a lot of these. So, it doesn't make sense to update each method individually. I'm looking for a Hybris configuration or customization that can change the default selection.

Answer (score 0):

you can switch the order of converters in **springmvc-servlet.xml**

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <ref bean="xmlHttpMessageConverter"/>
<!--            <ref bean="customJsonHttpMessageConverter" /> -->
<!--            <ref bean="customXmlHttpMessageConverter" /> -->
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```